# How to cope with the error of currupted heap(in debug mode) which arise due to different build flags of libraries involved in a project

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, build, heap-corruption

**Brief introduction:**
I am refactoring win32 application, I use VS 2008.
The application consists of both of my own dll and 3-rd party dll`s.

**Issue:**
When I run the application in the debug mode and execute some action the error is raised: the application programm has triggered a breakpoint, heap is corrupted.

**Actions undertaken:**
I have searched the internet and found that this error may be because of different build flags (multi-threaded debug `/MD` and multi-threaded debug dll `/MDd`) were used for dlls within the project(which results that they use different c runtime libraries, and for each library own list for work with memory is maintained this therfore can lead to the heap corruption).
I have checked my dlls - they all have the same flag: debug multithreaded dll. So I think that one of the 3-rd party DLL maybe was built with multi-threaded debug flag.

**Questions:**

- Is it possible to find out with what flag 3-rd party library was
  built, if so how can I do this.
- How can I sort you my issue of
  different build flags?
- Is my guess about that error is due to
  different build flags is correct?

Comment: Do you have this problem when you run a release build?

Comment: I think it might not be the flags thing.  If it were the flags, your program won't compile at all.

Comment: Not just different choices for the /M option, those DLLs might be using an entirely different version of the CRT.  You will need to rebuild them with the same settings and same compiler.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I haven`t tried to run release build, it is a very large project and it will be very time consuming operation to make a release build, so this is the last option I shall try

Comment: @Hans Passant how can I rebuild 3-rd party libraries if I have only binary files of that libraries(I haven`t got source code)

Comment: @ gongzhitaao - don`t you think that compilation and linking are 2 different processes???

Comment: When the debugger breaks when reporting stack corruption you know which function is called and who calls it. Having the declaration of the function you are calling and a small snippit of code showing how you call it would be very helpful. You should break it down into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) to make it easier to investigate the problem.

Comment: @Captain Obvlious point of the heap corruption and point where debugger break can be very different, so posting a code snippet which you requested doesn`t make sense. Still where are several questions what I posed, on which you can answer even without any code snippets.

Comment: I'm fairly sure you are looking at the wrong problem. In your question you said "stack corruption", now you said "heap corruption". If it's the stack you might be able to track it down by reducing the code before the crash to a minimum. If it's the heap, you could try to insert heapchecks in various places where the corruption might occur.

Comment: You could also try to remove the 3rd party DLL from your app or replace it with a dummy dll to see if that's the culprit. However as I said I think you're just witnessing real stack corruption due to an error in your program, not any runtime issues.

Comment: @Excelcius - sorry, it was mistype, it is about heap corruption

Comment: Where are you getting these third-party libraries from? You should be able to ask the vendor how they were compiled and what version of the CRT they target. You should also be able to obtain updated versions that are compatible with your build environment. If not, you may not be able to use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to find out with what flag 3-rd party library was built, if so how can I do this

Yes.  C or C++ DLLs built with Visual Studio versions 2005 and 2008 require a manifest that states what version of the C runtime DLL they need.  You can see it with VS, File + Open + File, select the DLL and open the node labeled "RT_MANIFEST".  Resource ID 2 is the manifest that states the type and version of the CRT.  It should match yours.  Export it to make it easier to read.  If it is missing then it either wasn't built with /MD or used a completely different version of VS, which in itself is bad news.

> How can I sort you my issue of different build flags?

You can't.  You'll need to contact the 3rd party and request a build that's compatible with yours.

> Is my guess about that error is due to different build flags is correct?

It is possible but not terribly likely.  Having a mismatch does not automatically cause a crash, a programmer can certainly design the DLL interface so that's never an issue.  You can typically tell from the function signature and documentation.  The problem case is where the DLL allocates an object and you are supposed to release it.  It will be obvious when the function returns a pointer.  Or a standard C++ class library object like std::string.  Less obvious is when it throws an exception.  Such a problem is also highly repeatable, it will bomb consistently, not occasionally.

The biggest mistake you are making is asking this question here.  You should be talking to a programmer employed by that 3rd party that has worked on this DLL.  He'll know the *exact* answer to your questions and can very easily solve your problem.  If you cannot get this kind of support then you should **not** be using these DLLs, they'll make your life miserable for a long time to come.